# Android actionbar background same color as text

Tags: android, xamarin, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-theme

This is my first project working with Android (Xamarin) and i was trying to style the ActionBar. I succesfully changed the background color, but now the text within it is either gone or the same color as the background. I think the second because i only changed the background. Below is my Styles.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="hme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/hme.ActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/hme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="hme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/hme.ActionBar.Text</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/primary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="hme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="hme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And here is a screenshot on Gyazo of how it looks. (Not enough rep to post a picture): http://gyazo.com/161cd58ced1f7a147b29f8ee6aa401af

I checked other fixes on SO on diffent questions but nothing seems to work, can anybody help me?

Comment: If i change "@color/primary" to "@color/black", both the text and the actionbar is black

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
```

into your `hme` style:

```
<style name="hme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/hme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/hme.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Check also:

```
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/black</item>
```

may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But this isn't working, i added the lines you provided and the actionbar is still like the screenshot i provided.

Comment: @Dylan2308 Replace `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid` with `android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.Solid`. I tested it, and it's works

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks! It's working now